# Gtest file not found by g++

Tags: g++, googletest

I run a code which needs `gtest`, but terminal shows:

> 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found

Here is the command:

```
$ g++ -w -I ../gtest/include/gtest -I../snap-core -I../glib-core -c run-all-tests.cpp
```

I think I add the path of `gtest`, but system did not find it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
-I ../gtest/include/gtest
```

to

```
-I ../gtest/include/
```

because you are looking for the tile `gtest/gtest.h`, not `gtest/gtest/gtest.h`